# Prometheus not capturing data for counter

Tags: python-3.x, monitoring, prometheus, sanic, prometheus-node-exporter

Prometheus is not able to capture data for the counter if calling increment from ipython console or celery tasks. Counter is worked for API request but outside of API request not worked like if i tried it from Ipython console, from celery tasks to increment the counter.

Prometheus is also not thrown any exceptions.

```
# Using Sanic python framework (async) and python 3.6.
Here are the library Details:
sanic==0.7.0
ipython
prometheus-client==0.5.0
python 3.6.5
```

Here is the config I am using in Sanic Python app to configure Prometheus:

```
class MetricsHandler(HTTPMethodView):
    """prometheus metrics exporter"""

    async def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        registry = None
        if 'prometheus_multiproc_dir' in os.environ:
            registry = core.REGISTRY
        else:
            registry = CollectorRegistry()
            multiprocess.MultiProcessCollector(registry)
        data = generate_latest(registry)
        return raw(data, content_type=CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST)

# ipython console example:
In [1]: Prom_Count = Counter('Prom_Counter', 'prom counter', ['func', 'count'])
In [2]: Prom_Count.labels("test", "count").inc()

prometheus_multiproc_dir enviroment varibale is also set.
```

Previously we were using sanic-prometheus library:

```
prometheus-client==0.2.0
sanic-prometheus==0.1.4
wrapt==1.10.11
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider doing this:

```
def get_registry():
    if 'prometheus_multiproc_dir' in os.environ:
        registry = CollectorRegistry()
        multiprocess.MultiProcessCollector(registry)
    else:
        registry = REGISTRY
    return registry
```

And then pass registry to `Counter` constructor:

```
Prom_Count = Counter('Prom_Counter', 'prom counter', ['func', 'count'], registry=get_registry())
```

Once I have faced such problem and it worked for me

Comment: it worked in ipython console but not worked in celery tasks.

Comment: The issue I faced in celery_tasks was the server running in celery instance didn't provide a response for the /metrics API call.
If you can see the count via collect() call and the data is not available in the /metrics API call, most probably this is the issue.

Comment: @Arjunsingh did you ever figure this out? I can get a metrics endpoint served alongside Celery, but my custom counters never get updated.

Comment: @dacox
I dont rememer the exact issue, but I remember that it had some registration or a file path issue.